# OpenCV logo recognition based ICPR 2010 article

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, image-recognition

I'm currently looking on this article:

Li, Zhe, Matthias Schulte-Austum, and Martin Neschen. "Fast logo detection and recognition in document images." Pattern Recognition (ICPR), 2010 20th International Conference on. IEEE, 2010.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B32aBI__7fcCNVIzeEpRM3ItcWc/view?usp=sharing) you can find the pdf.

I'm not sure about some of the method. I would like to implement it in my OpenCv.

Can I know how should I implement it using OpenCV?

EDIT : In the article, they stated about scale and rotation invariant shape descriptor but I'm not sure what is it and how to use it in OpenCV. Any Idea?

Comment: You're going to need to elaborate and be more specific about the problem you're facing.

Comment: In the article, they stated about scale and rotation invariant shape descriptor but I'm not sure what is it and how to use it in OpenCV. @AlfieJ.Palmer

Comment: Elaborate in the post, not the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to answer, but this paper is very poor on the details. 
The only *clear* thing is the definition of the descriptor, but it lacks an accurate description regarding:

- layers
- line profiles
- prototypes
- verification procedure

So, you'll find a lot of difficulties while implementing this method (I know that by personal experience :D).

My advice is (if it's possible) to find another paper with a detailed description of the method you can easily implement. Or find the source code of a good method (some paper cite the link to the code, or just find good university  research teams that will probably have a link to the code they used).

Regarding the computation of the descriptor (that you highlighted in the paper):

> For every connected component, its convex hull is calculated. Figure 2 gives an example. The black area is a connected component and the dashed line is the 
>   convex hull of it. For a convex hull, its orientation θ using the 2th moments, the square root of the variance of the main axis with respect to the orientation σmax, the square root of the variance on its orthogonal direction σmin, the maximum length lmax, minimum edge lmin, and the square root of its size lsize are also calculated.

You can do this in OpenCV by doing:

- connected componets -> `findContours`
- convex hull -> `convexHull`
- moments -> `moments`
- all others -> you need to work with the points on the contours, or the vertices of the convex hull.

**My advice is still to find a better described method.**
Not all papers at ICPR are good, and this is one of that!